# Powershell variable Path

Tags: powershell, path

I'm sorry if that question already got asked but I didn't find anything around  here so here I go:

So I wrote a little PowerShell Script to ease the work for our IT Colleagues (Ping IPs/Computernames, open the Log files of the User, start a remote job of the computer etc.)

To start a remote job on given IP / Computername, I used this:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Toolv1\RemoteControlViewer_SCCM2012\CmRcViewer.exe $objTextBox.Text
```

This works fine on my Computer at the moment, but how do I insert a variable Path that uses the current Path + `*\RemoteControlViewer_SCCM2012\CmRcViewer.exe $objTextBox.Text` so I can share my Script with my colleagues without changing the Path each time in the script?

I already tried things like:

```
($PSScriptRoot + \RemoteControlViewer_SCCM2012\CmRcViewer.exe) $objTextBox.Text
```

But I guess I'm doing something wrong.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Join-Path` to construct the full path, then `&` to invoke the executable:

```
& (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot RemoteControlViewer_SCCM2012\CmRcViewer.exe) $objTextBox.Text
```